# ADO.net entity model not refreshing data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have an ADO.net entity model from a mysql database, the database stores images locations or urls in a table called multimedia, there is a page that displays this images in a gallery. Whenever I save a new image from the website or directly into the database it won't show up in the gallery until I change something in the code (anything, this seems to refresh the model), or go to the model and right click and update it.

I tried `model.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, model.multimedia)` and `model.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, model.multimedia)`, from the controller nothing happens.

If I refresh the model from visual studio the images do show up. So the question is how can I refresh the data without having to update the model from Visual Studio?

Comment: how do you handle the data context. If you create an instance of your data context and store it, then access it when you need, your entity model can appear not to update until you redeploy. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: pburgess, as I was copying some code thinking about the data context as you pointed out, I saw what was wrong, the instance for the model in that controller was static, so you solved my question,it's working now thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, if you could post the answer so the question doesn't appear unanswered that will help!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, data context was static